# How do you scan redirected files in C (STDIN)?

Tags: c, scanf, io-redirection

Say I'm calling a program:

```
$ ./dataset < filename
```

where filename is any file with x amount of line pairs where the first line contains a string and second line contains 10 numbers separated by spaces. The last line ends with "END"

How can I then start putting the first lines of pairs (string) into:

```
char *experiments[20] // max of 20 pairs
```

and the second lines of the pairs (numbers) into:

```
int data[10][20] // max of 20, 10 integers each
```

Any guidance? I don't even understand how I'm supposed to scan the file into my arrays.

**Update:**

So say this is my file:

```
Test One  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  
END
```

Then redirecting this file would mean if I want to put the first line into my *experiments, that I would need to scan it as such?

```
scanf("%s", *experiments[0]);
```

Doing so gives me an error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What is incorrect about this?

Say my file is simply numbers, for ex:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then,
`scanf("%d", data[0][0]);` works, and will hold value of '1'. Is there an easier way to do this for the whole line of data? i.e. `data[0-9][0]`.

Comment: Treat the redirected file exactly as you would treat a user giving input from the keyboard. You can use scanf normally, for example.

Comment: `scanf("%s", *experiments[0]);` fails because you haven't (at least in the snippets shown above) allocated any storage for `experiments[0]`. `experiments` is declared as an array of pointers to strings; now you have to allocate the actual strings.

Answer (score 2):

find the pseudo-code, code explains how to read the input

```
int main()
{ 

    char str[100]; // make sure that this size is enough to hold the single line
    int no_line=1;

    while(gets(str) != NULL && strcmp(str,"END"))
    {    
            if(no_line % 2 == 0)
            {
                /*read integer values from the string "str" using sscanf, sscanf can be called in a loop with %d untill it fails */   
            }  
            else
            {
                /*strore string in your variable "experiments" , before copying allocate a memory for the each entry */ 
            }
         no_line++;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirected file is associated with the FILE * `stdin`. It's already opened for you...

otherwise, you can treat it the same as any other text file, and/or use the functions that are dedicated to standard input - with the only exception that you cannot seek in the file and not retrieve the size of the input.

Comment: Uh, minus the ability to seek, or get the overall size, I should add. Treat it as a stream only.

Comment: If you need it to be seekable, or it's very convenient for it to be seekable, and the file isn't enormous, there's really no reason not to slurp the whole file into a buffer. Given the sizes implied by the original question, that would probably be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: `prog < file` will result in a seekable `stdin`, as long as `file` is seekable itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the data sizes you're talking about, by far the easiest thing to do is just slurp all of the content into a buffer and work on that: you don't have to be super-stingy, just make sure that you don't overrun.

If you want to be super-stingy with memory, preallocate a 4kB buffer with `malloc()`, progressively `read()` into it from `stdin`, and `realloc()` another 4kB every time the input exceeds what you've already read. If you don't care so much about being stingy with memory (e.g. on a modern machine with gigabytes of memory), just `malloc()` something much bigger than the expected input (e.g. a megabyte) and bug out if the input is more than that: this is far simpler to implement but less general/elegant.

You then have all of the input in a buffer and you can do what you like with it, which depends too strongly on the format of the input for me to say how you should approach that part.